# SQL query for the below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 tables 1 with student detail 2 with Item detail and 3 with student completion detail.

```
**Table 1**

Stud Id     Stud Name    
1           aaa    
2           bbb    
3           ccc

**Table 2**
Item ID Item Name       
I1      Item1       
I2      Item2       
I3      Item3
```

This is what I get when I put join between these 3 table.

## Note : there will not be an entry in the completion table if the student has not completed an item.

```
**Table 3**     
Stud Id     Item ID Completion date    
1           I1          1/1/2000    
1           I2          1/2/2000    
3           I2          3/3/2003
```

**Required output**

```
Stud Id     Item ID completion date    
2           I2          NULL    
1           I3          NULL
```

enter code here
**There will not be any entry in the 3rd table with Completion date as null**

Comment: *there will not be an entry in the completion table if the student has not completed an item* means that there is no row in the completion table or that there is a row with null in completion date?

Comment: Did you try anything for above scenario ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stud.*, itm.*, comp.*
FROM student stud, item itm
LEFT OUTER JOIN completion comp
  ON stud.id = comp.studentId AND itm.id = comp.itemId
WHERE comp.studentId IS NULL
```

This selects all rows from `student` and `item` for which there is **no** entry in `completion`.

The base selection is the *cross product* of all `student`s and all `item`s.

The *outer* join connects `student`, `item` and `completion` *without* restricting the selection of rows.

The `WHERE` condition then restricts the result set to only those rows which, after the outer join, appear to have a `NULL` `studentId` in `completion` (any other non-null column of `completion` would work.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what u r looking for -

```
SELECT TempTable.StudID, TempTable.ItemID, Table3.CompletionDate FROM
(select t1.StudID, t2.ItemID
FROM 
Table1 t1 
cross join Table2 t2) TempTable 
left join Table3 ON TempTable.StudID = Table3.StudID AND TempTable.ItemID = Table3.ItemID
WHERE Table3.CompletionDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply write this as:

```
select s.student_id, c.item_id, c.completion_date
from students s cross join
     items i left join
     completion c
     on c.student_id = s.student_id and c.item_id = i.item_id
where c.completion_date is null;
```

The `cross join` generates all combinations of students and items.  The `left join` keeps all those rows and adds matching completion dates.  The `where` clause keeps the non-matches.